# Using ngStorage in a Cordova application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing an Angular JS cordova application and wonder about the overhead of ngStorage vs just using window.localStorage. I don't want to add yet another module if I don't have to . Thanks 
Andy

Comment: Rather than use localStorage you might consider a cordova plugin for better storage options per platform such as https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage

Comment: What is your actual *question* here?  As written, this feels like a rant in disguise, and more like you are looking for validation on your preference for not using a module, rather than help with an actual issue.

Comment: The question is , what is the advantage of using ngStorage? It seems that I can achieve the same result by using the built in mechanism. Aside from fact that ngStorage  is "the angular way"

Comment: there are plenty of advantages to using a module like ngStorage;  for example, automatic synchronization across browser tabs, a more natural pattern for accessing elements, a more testable solution, more easily readable code, etc.... however, this site is for questions related to *problems*, not questions of preference or library comparisons/recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

> It's better to use localStorage rather than adding an extra module in
>   the app; both are doing the almost same thing.

If you are looking for more advanced storage capabilities like creating a local database then go for any plugin or use webSql storage.

A simple example of webSQL storage.

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, "foobar")');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (2, "logmsg")');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me.